# Laravel Campo updated_at muestra 2h menos

Tags: php, laravel, php7, php5, laravel-6

tengo una máquina linux con mysql.

En la configuración de mi php.ini (php 7.3) tengo esto

```
[Date]
date.timezone = "Europe/Madrid"
```

Actualmente mi hora en españa són las 08:35, y si hago este comando en mysql me devuelve la hora exacta.

```
MariaDB [(none)]> SELECT now();
+---------------------+
| now()               |
+---------------------+
| 2021-04-07 08:35:25 |
+---------------------+
1 row in set (0.000 sec)
```

Luego tengo un proyecto en laravel donde un modelo llamado Cars tiene

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('cars', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id')->unique();
    ....
    $table->timestamps();
   });
}
```

El problema lo tengo en una consulta cuando hago un "update" me coje la hora GMT (es decir 2 horas menos), si hago algo como esto fecha_envio y created_at me pone "08:35", en cambio en updated_at "06:35"

```
            Cars::create([
                'fecha_envio' => Carbon::now()->timezone('Europe/Madrid'),
                'created_at' => Carbon::now()->timezone('Europe/Madrid'),
                'updated_at' => Carbon::now()->timezone('Europe/Madrid')
            ]);
```

Comment: Ya te dieron la respuesta que es cambiar el `timezone` de `config/app.php`, una vez hecho no es necesario ingresar datos manualmente al timezone(`created_at y updated_at`) porque el metodo `create` lo hace por defecto

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para no tener que escribir cada vez que quieras insertar una fecha en la DB. Es mejor configurarlo directamente en `config/app.php` asi `'timezone' => 'Europe/Madrid'`.

Ya después bastaría con solo colocar `'updated_at' => Carbon::now()` para actualizar el campo.

Comment: Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 1):

en el archivo config/app.php setea tambien el timezone

```
'timezone' => 'Europe/Madrid',
```

Comment: Muchas gracias.